# How to make Ubuntu 18.04 and Visual Studios run faster?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, windows, visual-studio-code

I am new to Ubuntu Linux and just installed version 18.04 on my computer alongside Windows in dual-boot mode. However, after three weeks, Linux started to be very slow, and it will even crash a few times a day when it is not able to run my code efficiently enough. It will stop building a package completely when I run `catkin build` such that I am forced to switch off my laptop.

I have tried the following:

- Looking at CPU specs with `lspcu`, which are good
- Looking at the omputer make and model, gotten with the `system information` part of `sudo dmidecode | less`
- Some of the solutions found on the following website: https://www.maketecheasier.com/linux-running-too-slow-heres-how-to-find-the-cause/. Such as: checking my CPU size (seems okay), examine CPU load with `top` (no process seems to be abusing my CPU usage) and check if my hard drive is overworking with `iotop` (it is not).
- Examining the system with `systemd-analyze blame`:

  ```
          19.606s apt-daily.service
          6.913s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          4.019s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          3.163s apt-daily-upgrade.service
          2.258s bolt.service
          1.391s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-66.mount
          1.354s snap-onenote\x2ddesktop-13.mount
          1.352s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-826.mount
          1.337s dev-sda7.device
          1.332s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-570.mount
          1.241s snap-dub-53.mount
          1.206s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1514.mount
          1.172s snap-snapd-11107.mount
          1.100s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-884.mount
          1.031s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-148.mount
          1.013s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-103.mount
           993ms snapd.service
           971ms snap-core-10958.mount
           912ms snap-code-59.mount
           911ms dev-loop4.device
           878ms dev-loop5.device
           857ms fwupd.service
           835ms dev-loop2.device
  ```

It seems like the upper lines are taken up a lot of time, so maybe this is a cause of the problem?

- It should be noted that my Ubuntu running slow is mainly caused when I am using Visual Studio Code for too long - when my Ubuntu has just started, it runs fine, but after a while it gets slower and slower. I checked again with the `top` command the CPU usage when running a code in Visual Studio Code and it seems like maybe this causes a problem since cc1plus command runs at 99-100% CPU:

[image: Result of top command: cc1plus running at 99-100% CPU]

- I have looked at /var/log/syslog errors as well with `cat var/log/syslog | grep 'error'` and the following error occurred multiple times:

```
Apr 16 13:48:06 jessie-HP-ZBook-Studio-G3 gnome-shell[1321]: Error setting property 'Powered' on interface org.bluez.Adapter1: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.Blocked: Blocked through rfkill (g-io-error-quark, 36)
```

Other errors that occur (not as often, though) are:

```
Apr 16 13:48:07 jessie-HP-ZBook-Studio-G3 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1957]: [4212:4212:0416/134807.054559:ERROR:gpu_service_impl.cc(1177)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers can't recover from errors. GPU process will restart shortly.
Apr 16 15:11:04 jessie-HP-ZBook-Studio-G3 kernel: [ 6106.242652] traps: ocs2_controller[14048] general protection fault ip:7f96415d58da sp:7ffd54f40af8 error:0 in libocs2_centroidal_planner.so[7f96414fa000+258000]
Apr 16 15:18:21 jessie-HP-ZBook-Studio-G3 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1957]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
Apr 16 16:36:57 jessie-HP-ZBook-Studio-G3 kernel: [    0.173308] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB._OSC due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-531)
Apr 16 16:36:57 jessie-HP-ZBook-Studio-G3 kernel: [    6.312196] EXT4-fs (sda7): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Apr 16 16:36:57 jessie-HP-ZBook-Studio-G3 kernel: [    6.736341] hp_accel: probe of HPQ6007:00 failed with error -22
Apr 16 16:36:59 jessie-HP-ZBook-Studio-G3 snapd[1048]: stateengine.go:150: state ensure error: Get https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/sections: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: no such host
```

- Finally, I went to the folder /var/crash and look for files there (`ls -a`), however, no files are found, the only thing my terminal displays are dots: `.  ..`

Anyone who has any idea where to look for the cause of these crashes when running code, and if the main cause is my Ubuntu / dual boot or Visual Studio Code? I am sorry for stating such an unclear general question.  If anything else is needed I'll provide it.

EDIT: @heynnema suggested showing the output of the following commands:

- `ls -al /var/crash` :

```
total 8
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 apr  1 14:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root     4096 nov 17 15:50 ..
```

- `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`:

```
# swap was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=7d274857-3e37-4991-8dda-48a22bfdf7b6 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

- `sysctl vm.swappiness`:

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

- `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`
  Does not give any result
- Screenshot of SMART Data & Self Tests in application Disks:
  [image: SMART Data & Self tests]

EDIT 2: Outcome of the following commands for @heynnema:

- `sudo lshw -C memory`:

```
*-cache:0                 
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 0
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 128KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 1
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 128KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:2
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 2
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:3
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 3
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 6MiB
       capacity: 6MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 5
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
          product: M471A1K43CB1-CRC
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 0
          serial: 0305815B
          slot: Top-Slot 1(left)
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 1
          slot: Top-Slot 2(right)
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: HP
       physical id: b
       version: N82 Ver. 01.45
       date: 01/05/2020
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 15MiB
       capabilities: pci pcmcia upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: Memory controller
       product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 31
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e5348000-e534bfff
```

- `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`:

```
N82 Ver. 01.45
```

- Motherboard info with `sudo dmidecode -t 2`:

```
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 2, 17 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: HP
    Product Name: 80D4
    Version: KBC Version 11.75
    Serial Number: PFPLFM11T540O0
    Asset Tag:  
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
    Location In Chassis:  
    Chassis Handle: 0x0000
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0
```

- Computer model:

```
HP ZBook Studio G3
```

**EDIT** @heynnema I followed the Swap steps, however, when using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` and trying to comment out the line `/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0`, I cannot find it, see screenshot:
[/etc/fstab edit file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOMZU.png)

Comment: **What** crashes? You write "Linux crashes". Do you get a kernel oops? Or how do those crashes that you write about manifest themselves?

Comment: In your `top` output I see only one CPU being active with compiling; the others appear to be pretty idle. Make sure you activate parallel builds for better performance.

Comment: What CPU model do you have? Do you use SSD?

Comment: To me it apears you're running out oft memory (RAM), and it starts shuffling pages between swap and RAM which is a processor heavy task. Perhaps experiment with zram or buy some extra ...

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. I suspect that your 4G swap is too small. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Also show me screenshots of the `Disks` application **SMART Data & Tests** data window. This window is scrollable, so it may take two screenshots to get it all. Lastly, show me `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`.

Comment: @heynnema I added the outcome of the commands to the post

Comment: Thanks. I added some additional info requests.

Comment: @heynema I added the screenshot as well, but the other command does not give a result unfortunately

Comment: That's fine. No FPDMA errors is good. Give me a minute to write an answer for you.

Comment: @HuHa how do I activate parallel builds? Do I have to activate that within Visual Studio Code?

Comment: @N0rbert my CPU model is the following: `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz` . For SSD usage I added the screenshot of my SMART Data and Tests in the post

Comment: I don't know about Visual Studio, but with plain `make` you'd invoke it with the numbers of CPU cores that you have with the `-j` parameter. If you have 8 cores, it's `make -j8`; or more general `make -j$(nproc)`. I am sure they have something like that in Visual Studio, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SWAP**

I suspect that your 4G swap partition is too small for your current usage.

**Note**: You may need to add more RAM (See Update #1).

We'll increase your swap by creating a new /swapfile, editing /etc/fstab, and deleting your swap partition.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
```

<strike>sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile</strike>

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=8192

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 8G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

Comment out this line...

```
UUID=7d274857-3e37-4991-8dda-48a22bfdf7b6 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Add this line...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

Delete the old swap partition using `gparted`. **CONFIRM** that /dev/sda8 has UUID=7d274857-3e37-4991-8dda-48a22bfdf7b6 by using `sudo blkid | grep -i swap`. If they match, then delete the /dev/sda8 partition. **BE CAREFUL HERE**.

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Update #1:**

**catkin build**

I'd recommend changing `catkin build -j1 package_name` to `catkin build -j7 package_name` (for using 7 CPUs on a 8 CPU system) to optimize the build process.

**BIOS**

HP ZBook Studio G3 Mobile Workstation

You have BIOS version N82 Ver. 01.45 from Jan 17, 2020. There's a newer BIOS version 01.52 Rev.A available from Nov 6, 2020 [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-zbook-studio-g3-mobile-workstation/8934839).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS

**Memory**

You have one, of two, memory slots filled with a 8G SODIMM.

```
 *-bank:0
      description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
      product: M471A1K43CB1-CRC
      vendor: Samsung
      physical id: 0
      serial: 0305815B
      slot: Top-Slot 1(left)
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
```

Fill the 2nd empty slot with another 8G Samsung M471A1K43CB1-CRC for 16G total RAM, with memory interleaving. See [https://www.amazon.com/Samsung-Notebook-Memory-M471A1K43CB1-CRC-DDR4-2400/dp/B06XPWJJPL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XPWJJPL).

Note: I need to check what the maximum RAM for this computer is...

[image]

Note: Source https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-zbook-studio-g3-mobile-workstation/8934839/product-info

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123146/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-how-to-make-ubuntu-18-04-and-visual-studios-run).

Answer (score -1):

i tried many ways ended up asking from Microsoft technician

he said if lower amount of startup addons didnt help
the real solution for it is to run on SSD!

i ended up buying samsung 980 pro 7kRW nvme

to be honest compare to before its like comparing flying bird to little turtle!
its little costly but at least  it wont piss me off every time i use Visual studio